# Binding Vuforia and ARCore cameras in Unity to use image target recognition for primary placement

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

I have been working on a Unity project which uses a vuforia camera to lock a city layout to an image. However, my main issue is a typical one with image targets in that when there isn't enough detail from the original target in frame the model disappears.

My idea is to use a vuforia camera to identify a specific target, but then lock the model into place using a parallel ARCore camera in order that I can use the orientation sensors of the device to lock the city in position.

I am sure this is possible, as there is an example on the experiments with google that achieves this, but I can't seem to find any technical details on the practicalities. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Example here:

https://experiments.withgoogle.com/ar/draw-and-dance

Comment: To clarify, you want the user to be able to move their device very close to the (printed, physical) image target without losing tracking? The only reliable way I've managed this was to break up the image target into smaller subsections that were their own image targets, with enough detail to track reliably. 6"x6" targets (there were 8 in a 2 wide 4 tall arrangement) was sufficient to get the device within 2 inches and still have a stable capture.

Comment: hey there, thanks for the reply. It was more along the lines of being able to look horizontally from a ground level and up towards the buildings so the existing tracking image isn't in view any more. I have experimented with ARCore in unity and this method works well - I think it's more the idea of adding in image targets to ARCore.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I haven't done anything like that and know nothing about ARCore. :\

Comment: You might need to find a way to share the camera frame byte array between Vuforia and ARCore. Not sure how open both systems are to achieve that. But something along that lines should work.

Comment: thanks for the reply - I got a response from vuforia that they will be implementing functionality with ARCore in a future release. They just don't have a date yet.

Comment: [This](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/wrld-unity-sdk-86284) came into my email late yesterday. Don't know if it really helps any, but it seemed to offer something very similar to what you were trying to do.

Comment: @Auniq Hi, where did you got the response that vuforia would work with arcore?.noticing that vuforia works with arkit, but not for arcore. I think you can try launch vuforia first, when image target is noticed, and tracked, you can disable vuforia tracking and enable arcore tracking, with last world to camera matrix as init arcore world to camera transform.

Comment: @flankechen on the vuforia dev forums, arcore will be supported from vuforia 7.2. As I have moved on from this project to other things, apologies for the delay in updating the thread and if this info isn't current.